# webpack 4 aspnetcore 2.2 HMR not reloading in browser

Tags: asp.net-core, webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm unable to rule out a compatibility issue with aspnetcore 2.2 and webpack 4 or a configuration issue on my end.

I need some help spotting the configuration issue if that is the cause.

- ASPNETCORE 2.2
- WEBPACK 4

When I make a change to a ".tsx" file, Visual Studio outputs that webpack has rebuilt, however the browser is not refreshing and there are no messages in the console. (I do however get the initial **HMR connected** message in the browser console).

**Visual Studio output**:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices:Information: webpack building...
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices:Information: Checking
>   started in a separate process...
>
> 754ms Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices:Information: webpack built
>   1e45bf5f88ad514f4a12 in 4940ms
>
> Compiled successfully. 
>   starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:44331/__webpack_hmr

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin'); 
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = (env) => {
const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);

const outputDir = (env && env.publishDir)
    ? env.publishDir
    : __dirname;

return [{
    mode: isDevBuild ? 'development' : 'production',

    devtool: 'inline-source-map',

    stats: { modules: false },

    entry: { 'main': './client/boot.tsx' },

    watchOptions: {
        ignored: /node_modules/
    },

    output: {
        filename: "dist/[name].js",
        path: path.join(outputDir, 'wwwroot'),
        publicPath: '/'
    },

    resolve: {   
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
    },

    devServer: {
        hot: true
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                include: /client/,
                loader: [
                    {
                        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                        options: {
                            useCache: true,
                            useBabel: true,
                            babelOptions: {
                                babelrc: false,
                                plugins: ['react-hot-loader/babel'],
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [             
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(path.join(outputDir, 'wwwroot', 'dist')),
        new CheckerPlugin()       
    ]
}];
```

};

**Startup.cs Configure:**

```
 if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
            {
                HotModuleReplacement = true                 
            });
        }
```

**package.json:**

```
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "*",
"@babel/preset-env": "*",
"@types/history": "4.6.0",
"@types/jest": "^23.3.2",
"@types/node": "^10.9.1",
"@types/react": "^16.7.13",
"@types/react-dom": "16.0.11",
"@types/react-hot-loader": "3.0.3",
"@types/react-router": "4.4.1",
"@types/react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
"@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.6",
"aspnet-webpack": "^3.0.0",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.0",
"babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
"babel-jest": "*",
"clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
"crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
"css-loader": "0.28.4",
"enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.4",
"event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
"file-loader": "0.11.2",
"file-saver": "^1.3.8",
"isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
"jest": "^23.6.0",
"jquery": "^3.2.1",
"json-loader": "0.5.4",
"moment": "^2.22.2",
"raf": "^3.4.0",
"react": "^16.6.3",
"react-deep-force-update": "2.1.1",
"react-dom": "^16.6.3",
"react-hot-loader": "^4.0.0",
"react-router-dom": "4.1.1",
"react-select": "^2.0.0",
"style-loader": "0.18.2",
"ts-jest": "^23.10.3",
"ts-loader": "^2.0.1",
"typescript": "^2.9.2",
"url-loader": "0.5.9",
"webpack": "^4.15.1",
"webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.1.3",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.22.2"
```

**EDIT:** (adding boot.tsx and app.tsx to show hot module loading)

**boot.tsx**

```
   import * as React from 'react';
   import { runWithAdal } from 'react-adal';
   import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
   import App from './app';
   import { authContext } from './authentication/azure/azureConfig';

   const DO_NOT_LOGIN = false;

   function renderApp() {   

       ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('react-app')
       ); 
   }

   runWithAdal(authContext, () => {  
       renderApp();
   }, DO_NOT_LOGIN);
```

**app.tsx**

```
   import * as React from 'react';
   import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader';
   import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
   import * as RoutesModule from './routes';
   import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
   import configureStore from './store/configureStore';

   let routes = RoutesModule.routes;

   const store = configureStore({});

   const baseUrl = 
   document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute('href')!;

   const App: React.SFC = () => <Provider store={store}>
```

;

```
   export default hot(module)(App);
```

Comment: I've developed a minimal reproducible example of an ASP.NET Core 2.2 app that won't HMR, but will HMR if I downgrade it to ASP.NET Core 2.1, but with no other changes. I think it's safe to say that HMR is broked in 2.2.

Comment: escaped the problem by going to aspnetcore 3.0

Answer (score 1):

According to your above configuration, you're packing the js files into `"wwwroot/dist/[name].js"`. The `output` information indicates that the `Webpack` hot reload feature is set up correctly. But it seems that `Webpack` has no idea on what the `index` page is. In other words, any changes made to `*.tsx` modules will only reload the compiled `wwwroot/dist/main.js` file.

For example, I create an `App.tsx` file:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export const App = () => <div>Hello World!</div>
```

and render the `App.tsx` in the `boot.tsx`.

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';  
import {App} from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("appconainer"));
```

When I serve the index page by `MVC` or `StaticFiles`, and then test with your configuration, `Webpack` won't know it should make a request to `home/index` action (or some "index.htm" url) to refresh.

**A possible approach to fix**

Since you've installed the `react-hot-loader` package, one approach is to use a `hot()` function to convert the root component to be [`hot-exported`](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/#getting-started):

```
// file: `App.tsx`
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root'

export const App = () => <div>Hello World!</div>

export const HotApp = hot(App);        // make it hot-exported!
```

and render the `hot-exported` root component:

```
// file: root.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {HotApp} from "./App";         // use the Hot-Exported component as the root component

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("appconainer"));
```

For more details,  see [docs here](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader)

Comment: Thanks for the details answer. I followed the example provided on the link, and changed react-hot-loader to the latest version. However I'm still unable to get it working. I revised my question to show the code I added in boot.tsx and app.tsx.

Comment: @proggrock I'm wondering is the packed main.js reloaded automatically ?

Comment: The issue you explain in your answer seems to be the same one I am having. HMR is working, I can see in both the VS code debug console AND the browser console that "[HMR] bundle rebuilding". In the VS Code debug console I get the "Compiled successfully" but in the browser console I don't. My App isn't a SPA so I guess I would need a full page refresh. Anyway to make WebpackDevMiddleware do that? :)

Comment: @billyjean the way to make it hot-exported works for me .